# Activation Key for Windows 8.1 and 8.1 Pro, are they different?

Tags: windows-8.1, windows-activation

I know the different capabilities of W8.1 and W8.1 Pro.
Anyway, a friend wants to sell me an activation key for Windows 8.1 Pro but I have Windows(R) and its description says RETAIL channel, it means I have Windows 8.1 (not the Pro version). The question is: can I activate my windows 8.1 with that key for windows 8.1 Pro?

Comment: They are indeed different.  You can upgrade from Windows 8.1 to Windows 8.1 Professional

Comment: yes, I did it, no problem.